# Stored procedures in NOSQL

Tags: database, nosql

We have developed a web application by using PostgreSQL. We have recently decided to migrate to the NOSQL world (we have choose cassandra as database) by using the advantage of Hadoop/MapReduce). This will allow us to migrate to Big data world: We are treating a huge amount (billions of records) of data coming from different sources.

Our application contains some calculation-algorithms which are very complicated. In the actual version (using postgresql), those algo are implemented in stored procedure. Now, we want to migrate this stored procedure to cassandra.

I have too question's:

1- Is this technically feasible?
2- What is the best way to test the feasibility?
3- Do we have to expect a big performance enhancement by doing this migration.

Thank you for you support.
Walid

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing really equivalent to a Stored Procedure in Cassandra, but the newly created [Triggers](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cassandra-2-0-prototype-triggers-support) might help you. Triggers can be written in any [JVM language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) and can be placed directly on a Cassandra node -- they are fired **BEFORE** the statement is executed so you might put your logic inside here. If triggers don't match your needs the only alternative I see is to put the logic directly in the application.

As far as the question number 3 it depends. Cassandra offers linear scalability, this means that if X nodes supports Y transactions/second NX nodes can reach NY transactions/second -- but performance enhancement (or detraction) can't be predicted without all informations (and, even in this case, it wouldn't be easy)

HTH, Carlo

Answer (score 0):

With Aerospike, you can use [User Define Functions](http://aerospike.com/docs/architecture/udf.html). Aerospike's user defined functions can operate on a single record or operate read-only on a collection of records.